# Problems after update Android Studio to 3.0 version

Tags: android, guava

I have received troubles after update Android Studio to 3.0 version. Firstly Gradle showed below error:

```
    Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

I made below actions:

1) Build --> Clean Project

2) Build --> Rebuild Project

3) Delete .gradle folder from my project

4) File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

All below actions were not helpfull for me.

Next actions made by me:

4) Add `"multiDexEnabled true"` and `"compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'"` to build.gradle file.

5) Add `"android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" "` to manifest file.

Currently I can see below error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\KamitoSoft\MEforYOU\Program Kod\039MEforYOU\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Krzysztof Kamiński\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava-jdk5\17.0\463f8378feba44df7ba7cd9272d01837dad62b36\guava-jdk5-17.0.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [guava-jdk5-17.0.jar:com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class]))

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\KamitoSoft\MEforYOU\Program Kod\039MEforYOU\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Krzysztof Kamiński\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava-jdk5\17.0\463f8378feba44df7ba7cd9272d01837dad62b36\guava-jdk5-17.0.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [guava-jdk5-17.0.jar:com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class]))
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\KamitoSoft\MEforYOU\Program Kod\039MEforYOU\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Krzysztof Kamiński\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava-jdk5\17.0\463f8378feba44df7ba7cd9272d01837dad62b36\guava-jdk5-17.0.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [guava-jdk5-17.0.jar:com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class]))
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:187)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.execute(OutputWriter.java:79)
    at proguard.ProGuard.writeOutput(ProGuard.java:427)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:175)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:61)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MainDexListTransform.shrinkWithProguard(MainDexListTransform.java:232)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MainDexListTransform.transform(MainDexListTransform.java:184)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\Users\Krzysztof Kamiński\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava-jdk5\17.0\463f8378feba44df7ba7cd9272d01837dad62b36\guava-jdk5-17.0.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [guava-jdk5-17.0.jar:com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class])
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:188)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:158)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:176)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [guava-jdk5-17.0.jar:com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class]
    at proguard.io.JarWriter.getOutputStream(JarWriter.java:138)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:92)
    at proguard.io.ClassRewriter.read(ClassRewriter.java:68)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65)
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:184)
    ... 50 more
```

I can not find guava implementation in my build.gradle file.
My build.gradle file looks like that:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    //buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kamitosoft.meforyou"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {

    //implementation ('me.dlkanth:stetho-volley:1.0') {
        //exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    //}
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    /*androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            })*/
    compile files('libs/mariadb-java-client-1.5.7.jar')
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    /*
            compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev62-1.22.0') {
                exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
            }
            */
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/cwac-merge-1.1.2.jar')
    compile 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev182-1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Current error which you can find in my post looks like that:

```
Duplicate zip entry [guava-jdk5-17.0.jar:com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class])
```

Error is generating by `Beta.class` and I should resolved it by excluding all occurences of `guava` in my `build.gradle` file. 
For example:

```
compile ('...........................') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }
```

I find `Beta.class` by use "Control + N" keyboard shortcuts (find class) in android studio. After use this option I can see:

[image]

I can not find `com.google.common.annotations` in my build.gradle file. Where I should use guava excluding option?

Could You help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have solved problem by excluded guana from com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1.
If you don't have idea where you should use guana exclude function you should try one by one.

```
compile ('com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1')
        {
            exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
        }
```

Comment: awesome this fixed my issue, added it to ```com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore``` in my case

Answer (score 1):

I could fix the issue by declaring `guava` with `api` in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    api 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
}
```

When using `compile` or `implementation` it fails with the error above.